# copy conditional formatting between hyperlinked cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, vba

How do I ensure the conditional formatting of a cell is also applied to its hyperlinked cell as well?

[image]

following is a basic example of what I am trying to do. Cell E6 has conditional formatting. Cell M7 is hyperlinked to cell E6. How do I ensure that M7 has the same formatting as E6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Hyperlink.SubAddess` to get a reference to its target range.  Next copy the target range and use `Hyperlink.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats` to copy all the formating over.  If you just want the Conditional Formatting then you'll have to itererate over the target's FormatConditions.

```
Sub ProcessHyperlinks()
    Dim h As Hyperlink
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each h In ws.Hyperlinks
            If h.SubAddress <> "" Then
                On Error Resume Next
                h.Range.FormatConditions.Delete
                Range(h.SubAddress).Copy
                h.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Extend the *Applies to* range with `,M7`

Include M7 in the Applies to range for the CF that already is formatted conditionally. For example assuming conditional formatting of E6:G24 is conditional upon the value of F15 being `AAAA`, such as with this formula rule:

```
  =$F$15="AAAA"
```

with applies to of `$E$6:$G$24`.

In Conditional Formatting Rules Manager select Applies to and append `M7`:

[image: SO38931080 example]

It is however possible that the functionality will depend on your exact situation.