# Conditional Formatting and FormulaText

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, excel-2016

Trying to solve this question: 
[copy conditional formatting between hyperlinked cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931080/copy-conditional-formatting-between-hyperlinked-cells).

I stumbled upon a problem -
Whenever my conditional formatting rule included *FORMULATEXT()*, it would only evaluate cells that were formulas, no longer looking at basic input cells (like a string or number).

To reproduce:

```
     A           B           C           D           E
1    =0          =A1         -           -           -
2    ="asdf"     asdf        -           -           -
3    -           -           -           -           -
4    -           -           -           -           -
5    -           -           -           -           -
```

Conditional Formatting rule (applied to `=$A$1:$E$10`):

```
=OR((A1="asdf"),(FORMULATEXT(A1)="=A1"))
```

Result:
[image]

For some reason cell B2 is not highlighted even though it should.
 Am I missing something? Is this a bug?

I admit this is a quite rare application of these formulas, but I'm curious..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FORMULATEXT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FORMULATEXT-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8) returns an error value in some cases:

> ...
>
> In the following cases, FORMULATEXT returns the #N/A error value::
>
> - The cell used as the Reference argument does not contain a formula.

If a formula parameter is an error value, then the whole formula will return this error value. So the `OR` will return `#N/A` instead of `True` or `False`. Unless you catch this error:

```
=OR(A1="asdf",IFERROR(FORMULATEXT(A1),"")="=A1")
```